# PhoneGap Android: $.getJSON("http://foo.com") not working (access permissions?)

Tags: jquery, json, cordova, getjson

Using Cordova-2.5.0 + jQuery 1.9.1, I'm trying to access a remote JSON file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("http://sub.foo.com/json.php",function(data) {
```

It works ok on my Chrome browser, but not on my Android Emulator (it stops when trying to access remote JSON file).

I did set permissions on 'AndroidManifest.xml'

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

and on 'config.xml'

```
<access origin="http://sub.foo.com" />
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer but I have a debug tip; Weinre 
http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/